# Map plotting with Basemap Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apt, python3, plot

I am trying to plot on a globe with basemap.  However, I get the following error listed below.  How can I get basemap to work?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "plotgm.py", line 3, in <module>
    from mpltoolkits.basemap import Basemap
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mpltoolkits'

sudo apt install python3-mpltoolkits.basemap
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-mpltoolkits.basemap is already the newest version (1.1.0+dfsg-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `mpltoolkits.basemap` installed for Python 3.
Are you using Python 2 to run your program?
Make sure you type
`python3 <filename>`

Comment: I am using Python3.6.6